# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Language Learning has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Rebecca J. Stones]

[image: Robert Columbia]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5149419879006208).

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to Rebecca J. Stones and Robert Columbia on the moderator election and thank you also to Ken Graham for participating in the election.

This was an election in which the new moderators would have previous moderator experience, regardless of who got elected. That's a luxury we don't always have.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone who participated in the election, especially those who did not win this time!